# Match first and stop

Tags: regex

I have some strings like the following:

```
Self-Service Portal - Company Name1 - Portal Header
Self-Service Portal - Company Name2 - Portal Footer
Self-Service Portal - Company Name1 - Portal Script
```

I want to extract the Company Name. So I did the following regex in Javascript

```js
var matchPattern = function( sourcestring) {
var re = /^.+\s+?-\s+?(.+?)\s+?-\s+?.+$/;
    var matches = re.exec(sourcestring);
    if( matches != null){
        return matches[1];
    }
   else{
        return 'Not Found';
   }
}

alert(matchPattern('Self-Service Portal - Company Name1 - Portal Header'));
alert(matchPattern('Self-Service Portal - Company Name1 - Portal Footer'));
alert(matchPattern('Self-Service Portal - Company Name2 - Portal Header'));
alert(matchPattern('Self-Service Portal - Company Name 2 - Portal - Footer'));
```

This works, except for the last string 'Self-Service Portal - Company Name1 - Portal - Footer'. 
Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest splitting the string with `-`:

```js
var matchPattern = function( sourcestring) {
    var re = /\s+-\s+/;
        var matches = sourcestring.split(re);
        if( matches != null){
            return matches[1];
        }
       else{
            return 'Not Found';
       }
    }


    document.write(matchPattern('Self-Service Portal - Company Name1 - Portal Header') + "<br/>");
    document.write(matchPattern('Self-Service Portal - Company Name1 - Portal Footer') + "<br/>");
    document.write(matchPattern('Self-Service Portal - Company Name2 - Portal Header') + "<br/>");
    document.write(matchPattern('Self-Service Portal - Company Name 2 - Portal - Footer') + "<br/>");
```

Your regex can work as expected if you use lazy matching with the first `.+`:

```
^.+?\s+?-\s+?(.+?)\s+?-\s+?.+$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hF6gK1/1), but it is very inefficient because it invloves much backtracking as `.+?` can also match `\s+?`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also the comment with the lazy matching. Well I'll go with your answer. Even id this is for a 1 time batch script and I don't have to care much about efficiency

Comment: I see. I just meant that you should be extremely careful with `.*`/`.+` and their lazy counterparts. Good luck.